Why React Openlayer cluster doesnt work on dynamic points?

    // Init map.
    useEffect(() => {
        const source = new VectorSource({
            wrapX: false,
            features: points
        });

        const clusterSource = new Cluster({
            distance: 40,
            minDistance: 10,
            source: source
        });


        const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
            // source: source,
            source: clusterSource,
            style: new Style({
                image: new Circle({
                    radius: 5,
                    fill: new Fill({color: 'red'})
                })
            })
        });
    }, []);

I can’t understand why when updating points they are not clustered, but points are visible.
Did it according to the instructions "Clustered Features" from the open-layers docs.
